# How to analyze this kind of crash log?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, crash-dumps

the crash log seems crash in line 90
[image]

but in my codes , it seems like line 90 will never can make a crash happen (the sessionManager is the AFHTTPSessionManager), any clue to fix this kind of crash ?
[image]

Comment: check your `delegate.appDataObject.oauth2AcessToken`, are you sure it's not a `nil`?

Comment: @ezatu丶 i think the nsstring format will make sure it will be safe even if the delegate.appDataObject.oauth2AcessToken is nil

Comment: You should add "Exception Breakpoint" to detech where is the actually crash.

Comment: see property of your `appdataobject` and `oauth2acesstoken` where you define.

Comment: @EmreGürses this crash is found only in online version occasionally , and i can't reproduce it in my debug version.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a factor, but only initialization methods should start with `init` in Objective C. It's possible that the name is confusing the runtime.

Comment: @DaveWeston thanks alot , this init method is not conform to the naming convention , and maybe this can make the release problem happen!